# Are NSString and similar excluded from MVC?

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller, nsstring

In MVC, every class should belong to either `View`, `Model` or `Controller`. `View` and `Model` should not know about each other. Therefore, this is bad:

```
@interface Person : NSObject    // Clearly a model class

@property (nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger age;

@end


@interface PersonInfoView : NSView    // Clearly a view class

@property (nonatomic) Person *personToDisplay;

@end
```

Instead, you would configure the `PersonInfoView` from the controller. So you might instead have this `PersonInfoView` class:

```
@interface PersonInfoView : NSView

@property (nonatomic) NSString *nameToDisplay;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger ageToDisplay;

@end
```

But as you see, `NSString` is in both a model and a view class! The only explanation would be that `NSString` is a controller, but that doesn't make sense at all.

My thought was then, maybe `NSString` (and similar classes) are excluded because they almost act as primitive C types?

Comment: There is no requirement for all classes to be a `View`, `Model` or `Controller`. In fact most are not. The point of MVC is how the model interacts with the view--via the controller. BTW, there are other version of MVC other than the one Apple has chosen.

Comment: That answers the question (thanks!) so if you want to, you can add it as an answer so that I can accept it as the solution.

Comment: Add the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no requirement for all classes to be a View, Model or Controller. In fact most are not.

The point of MVC is how the model interacts with the view--via the controller.

BTW, there are versions of MVC other than the one Apple has chosen.